# Loop through folders and create new subfolders for each then move images in Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, directory, shutil, mkdirs

Let's say I have a folder which has subfolders `project1, project2, project3, ...` in it.

[image]

In each of project, I have subfolders fixedly named `process`, `progress` and `session` in it, inside those subfolders, there are also other subfolders and image files.

Now I want to create subfolders `files1` for each `project` to move all the images from `process`, and create `files2` to move all the images from `progress` and `session`.

**Please note the names of images for each projects are unique, so we ignore image name duplicates issues.**

For creating `files1` for `project1`, I use:

```
import os
dirs = './project1/files1'

if not os.path.exists(dirs):
    os.makedirs(dirs)
```

But I need to loop through all the projects folders.

How could we do that in Python? Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For create `file1` and `file2` for each `project`:

```
# Remove non-images files
base_dir = './'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    for file in files:
        # print(file)
        pic_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        ext = os.path.splitext(pic_path)[1].lower()
        if ext not in ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg']:
            os.remove(pic_path)
            print(pic_path)

# create files1 and files2
for child in os.listdir(base_dir):
    child_path = os.path.join(base_dir, child)
    os.makedirs(child_path + '/file1', exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(child_path + '/file2', exist_ok=True)
```